# How to neglect the umask so as to create the file with given permission

Tags: c++, unix, solaris

I am creating a file using open function and using O_CREAT | O_EXCEL . I have passed the mode as "0666" . But by masking finally the permission allotted to it is -rw-r--r-- and not the
-rw-rw-rw- . Someone told me i can use umask (011) and then reset the original mask again .
But i dont know how to pass this in c++ program. This is the small snippet of What i am doing .

```
   # include <iostream>
   # include <stdio.h>
   # include <conio.h>
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <fcntl.h>

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
    int fd = open("C:\\Users\\Ritesh\\Music\\music.txt", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666);   
    getch();
    return 0;   
  }
```

creates file `C:\Users\Ritesh\Music\music.txt` with permission `-rw-r--r-- .` I want it to be `-rw-rw-rw-`

Comment: I'm so confused. How do you have a filesystem with Unix permission bits and DOS path names? And what O/S simultaneously provides `<sys/stat.h>` and `<conio.h>`?

Comment: @Rob Dont worry i just copied it While looking for header files for open. I am just using DEV c++ on my windows system .Actually i use solaris in my work place .  So Sorry if it has confused you .

Comment: So, which system are you asking about? Windows or Solaris?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mode_t old_mask;

old_mask = umask(011);
open( ... );
umask(old_mask);
```

Comment: does using `mode_t old_mask;` gives me the present mask setting ? and `umask( old_mask );` will set it back to original value?

Comment: @Invictus Yes, that is correct. (Better late than never!)

Comment: Note the umask is a process-wide value.  Changing its value will affect all other threads that are running.

Answer (score 2):

umask means permissions that you don't want to give to files by default. So if you want to control the permissions completely while creating a file, set umask to 0, which tells the os don't reserve any permissions and let you call the shot. like this:

```
int main()
{
    mode_t oldmask = umask(0);
    int fd = open("C:\\Users\\Ritesh\\Music\\music.txt", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666);
    close(fd);
    umask(oldmask);
    getch();
    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The ***only*** thread-safe way to set file permissions to be what you want is to set them explicitly with [`chmod()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chmod.html) or [`fchmod()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchmod.html) after creating the file (example without error checking):

```
int fd = open("C:\\Users\\Ritesh\\Music\\music.txt", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666);
fchmod(fd, 0666 );
```

If you use `umask()`, you will change the `umask` value for the entire process.  If any other threads are running you risk files getting created with unexpected permissions, which could lead to a security issue or other problems.  And any child process created while your changed `umask` value is in effect will be created with an unexpected `umask` value.